# Non-Incrementing Generated ID for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am currently trying to make a table with an ID that is unique and auto-generated by PostgreSQL but not-autogenerated and doesn't start from 1

Ideally, I'd prefer for it to be a certain length (ie 15 characters), completely random, and generated every time a row is added to the table. Is this something supported natively by PostgreSQL or do I have to use a third party or build my own algorithm?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PostgreSQL doesn't support this natively as shown [here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/blog/engineering/2015/05/20/why-auto-increment-is-a-terrible-idea/) and the solution is to use a UUID with the UUID extensions .

Comment: Starting with Postgres 13 you don't need an extension to generate UUIDs